# Shall we burninate the outside-world tag?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I see no use for this tag. I also dont see a reasonable number of questions that would use it. Its on meta. Can it be removed?

Comment: What is the tag, what is it supposed to mean, and what questions are using it?

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike The only question using it is [our list of programming languages](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-languages-have-been-created-by-pldi-users).

Comment: So it's a tag on meta, and has no tag wiki or usage guidelines, so it seems simpler to discuss in the comments of that question, or just remove it unilaterally. Anyway, that question seems to have been created by [a bot which also posts on CGCC](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/users/744/the-compiler), so perhaps it was simply using a template which uses a tag that makes sense on CGCC but not here. It also means we can't really ask the author what they intended the tag to mean, so I don't see any likelihood of a useful discussion about it. I edited to remove the tag.

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike The author of that post (though not the account who posted it) is @ RydwolfPrograms (SE won't let me @ him here for some reason), so it is very much possible to ask him :P

Comment: SE doesn’t let you @ people not already in the discussion (such as Rydwolf) @Bbrk24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag has been removed from the question it was on, so effectively burninated.

[image]